# question on identity theorem

Tags: entire-functions

For an odd integer $k\ge1$ , let $\mathbb{F}$ be the set of all entire functions f such that $f(x)=\vert{x^k}\vert$  for all $x\in(-1,1)$. Then the cardinality of $\mathbb{F}$ is

1.0

2.1

3.strictly greater than 1 but finite

4.infinite

f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^k,  & \text{if $x\in(0,1)$ } \\[2ex]
-x^k, & \text{if $x\in(-1,0)$ }
\end{cases}

consider convergent sequence {$\frac{1}{n}$} in (0,1)

Let g(z)=$z^k$ ,since $f(\frac{1}{n})=g(\frac{1}{n})$ on (0,1)

hence $f{(z)}=z^k$ on (-1,1) by using identity theorem.

similarly on (-1,1) i can show that $f{(z)}=-z^k$

but then how to conclude for final answer?

Answer (score 0):

If $f(z)=z^k$ on $(0,1)$, then $f(z)=z^k$ on $ \mathbb C$.

A similar argument gives $f(z)=-z^k$ on $ \mathbb C$.

Conclusion: no such function exists.

Comment: I am not getting . why such function cannot exist.?  Both $z^k$ and $-z^k$ are entire functions .Because  for $f(z)=z^k, so f(\frac{-1}{2})=-\frac{1}{2^k}$ , but mod should be positive hence such function does not exist or i have to use identity theorem?